# Call a method of a static member for initialization in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class that has a static member object. Initializing that static object means setting some of its parameter to a specific value; but this is done by a function from that object. i do not know how to do it if it is static. Any help?

---

To be more specific I have a static boost logger object per class. It has a `ClasName` attribute and setting this to the `name_of_the_class` value is done by `add_attribute("ClassName", boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>("MyClass"))` function. What is the best way to initialize the static logger? I have done:

```
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger< severity_levels > BoostLogger;

class MyClass
{
private:
  static BoostLogger m_logger;

public:
  MyClass()
  {
    MyClass::m_logger.add_attribute("ClassName", boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>("MyClass"));
  }
}

BoostLogger MyClass::m_logger; // And here I cannot call the add_attribute() function
```

I know that this is done every time I instantiate the class, so: What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I want to initialize the static logger only once per class, not once per instatiation

Comment: Add the line to any of your initialization function.

Comment: So I shall create a static `init` function?

Comment: Do you need to have at least one instance of MyClass for `m_logger` to be initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `BoostLogger` doesn't provide the constructor to `add_attribute` you may create your own function for that, something like:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    static BoostLogger m_logger;
};

BoostLogger CreateBoostLoggerWithClassName(const std::string& className)
{
    BoostLogger logger;
    logger.add_attribute(
        "ClassName",
        boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>(className));
    return logger;
}

BoostLogger MyClass::m_logger = CreateBoostLoggerWithClassName("MyClass");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can initialise the logger once e.g. with a static variable in your constructor:

```
MyClass()
{
  static bool logger_initialised = false;
  if (!logger_initialised)
  {
    MyClass::m_logger.add_attribute("ClassName", boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>("MyClass"));
    logger_initialised = true;
  }
}
```

Note that this is not thread-safe. But if you do not use threads, it will work and the logger will be initialised one time but only if you instantiate `MyClass`.

Comment: Not thread-safe in any way shape or form. Also not very elegant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So what is the best way?

Comment: There is no one best way. It depends on e.g. how costly the initialisation is.

Comment: For that class it is only once, or twice, but there are other classes that I want to have this kind of logger

Comment: I meant that if you prefer to wait with initialisation till the first instance of your class is created, and you don't care about thread safety, use my answer.

Comment: Your approach is not different than mine, except it has a static member more and an if that is always executer. Am I right?

Comment: No the approaches are different. Static variable `logger_initialised` keeps its value between constructor calls, so the condition in `if` will be met only the first time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all look at the [BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER.html)

Here is corrected version of your code.

**MyClass.h:**

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  static BoostLogger m_logger;  /*  This is declaration, not definition.
                                    You need also define the member somewhere */

public:
  MyClass() /*  So far as this is constructor, it may be called more than once,
                I think adding new static function will be better */
  {
    // MyClass::m_logger.add_attribute("ClassName", boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>("MyClass"));
    // AddAttribute("ClassName"); Uncomment this line if you're really need to add attribute in constructor
  }

  static void AddAttribute(std::string name) /* this function has been added as advice,
                                                if you're going add attributes as you
                                                did in question,
                                                remove function, and uncomment first              line in the constructor */
  {
    MyClass::m_logger.add_attribute(name, boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>("MyClass"));
  }
}
```

**MyClass.cpp:**

```
BoostLogger MyClass::m_logger = BoostLogger(); // This is definition of static member item
```

Comment: Yes, I have to edit the question... Now you can see where is the definition.

Comment: You don't need if you want. See my last changes in the answer. :)

Comment: Ok, so you say that I need a static function. But is this the best approach?

Comment: I think using static function is elegant, and makes code more readable. BTW, removing adding attributes in constructor will be able to add attributes even in main function, **without** instantiation of `MyClass`.

Comment: What is the best way to do it: `BoostLogger MyClass::m_logger = BoostLogger();` or `BoostLogger MyClass::m_logger;`?

Comment: @Edward: Why do you define the static member so strangely?

Comment: @sop Run this code: http://pastebin.com/vTwABEDS
And you'll get answer to your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it's much easy to understand.

Comment: @Edward I do not get it: I have run the both versions (Heavy `MyStruct::m_h = Heavy();` and `Heavy MyStruct::m_h/* = Heavy()*/;`) and the result is the same ... on my computer

Comment: @sop there are no difference, that's so there are no difference. So both version of initializations are correct and equal in point of view to performance. You can use both versions, and don't care about performance issues.
BTW, overload assignment operator, and you will still see same output.

Comment: Actually it is not guaranteed that the temporary and copy will be elided. It's just silly having that there; serves no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would like to see a topic about it. A code example, which will show difference on GCC and/or CC will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an `add_attribute` call, make it so that you can fully initialise `BoostLogger` with its constructor. Then simply provide the necessary argument when you define it.

Comment: Ok, it is an error there it is a `BoostLogger`, that is `typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger< severity_levels > BoostLogger;` And I have no access to it... Shall I make it a non-static BoostLogger?

Comment: Oh, so _now_ you tell us what `BoostLogger` is. What prevented you from providing this information at the outset? *Sigh*